# Swift func with generic where constraint is a protocol which self conforms

Tags: ios, swift, generics, protocols, swinject

I'm trying to write a static generic method which takes a protocol as an argument and register class instance in Swinject container as a protocol resolve.
It's important that I could not register a module as a protocol it does not conforms to.

I wrote something like this:

```
/// RegisterableModule guarantee that conformer has `create()` method returning self

public extension RegisterableModule {

    static func registerModule<P>(asProtocol proto: P.Type,
                                  in container: Container) {
        container.register(proto, name: nil) { (resolver) -> P in
            return self.create()
        }
    }
}
```

It does not compile because obviously Self may be not conforming to P

I also tried to specify generic constraint using `where`:

1. `where Self: P` does compile error "Type 'Self' constrained to non-protocol, non-class type 'P'"
2. `where self: P` does multiple compiles error.
3. `where Self: P.Type` does compile error "Type 'Self' constrained to non-protocol, non-class type 'P.Type'"
4. `where self: P.Type` does multiple compile errors.

I also wonder if I can specify a constraint that P can be protocol only.

Comment: `RegistarableModule` contains only `create()` method?

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunatelly, there is no way (yet) in Swift to define requirement of conformance to generic parameters, or require parameter to be a protocol.

This is the reason why Swinject's type-forwarding API [is not type safe](https://github.com/Swinject/Swinject/blob/master/Documentation/TypeForwarding.md#type-safety). There is a ["trick"](https://github.com/Swinject/Swinject/issues/339) that sort-of enables one to express a conformance requirement, however I'm not sure if it would be practical for your use-case:

```swift
extension RegisterableModule {

    static func registerModule<P>(
        asProtocol proto: P.Type, 
        in container: Container, 
        typeCheck: (Self) -> P
    ) {
        container.register(proto) { _ in self.create() as! P }
    }
}

MyModule.registerModule(
    asProtocol: MyProtocol.self, 
    in: container, 
    typeCheck: { $0 }
)
```

Comment: (yet)? Is there any rumor about "generic parameters as constraints?" :) Only thing that I can found is two Jira issues:
https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-5400
https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-5213

Comment: @TolgaOkur Not that I know of. It is just me being a bit optimistic :)

Answer (score 0):

Can you try it, I just added **P:SomeProtocol**

```
public extension RegisterableModule {

    static func registerModule<P:SomeProtocol>(asProtocol proto: P.Type,
                                  in container: Container) {
        container.register(proto, name: nil) { (resolver) -> P in
            return self.create()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't have SomeProtocol. What swift version do you use?

Comment: SomeProtocol is any custom type that you can create, I only created for illustration purpose. 
Here I am constraining the P so that it can only accept the types that conform to SomeProtocol.

Comment: But I want this one should be a protocol. 
No matter what exactly, but protocol, not a class which is conforming protocol.

There should be no way to pass `MyClass: AnyProtocol` as a proto because MyClass is not a Protocol, it's a class which is conforming protocol.